# php include file in array

Tags: php, arrays, include, file-get-contents

I am trying to create an array that should return some html as well of some other data through an ajax call. The thing is I need to include a php file that first has to build the HTML page, bue when I use a command like `file_get_contents()`:

```
$array['nav'] = array(
    1 => false
);

$array['content'] = array(
    1 => file_get_contents('filename.php')
);

$array['stylesheets'] = array(
    1 => 'admin'
);
```

It just returns all my php code as well in the array.. I have also tried to use `include()`, but it automatically displays all the HTML before I can echo a json-encoded array, which won't work with my AJAX call. Any idea how to solve this?

Ex.

**file_a.php**

```
$array['nav'] = array(
    1 => false
);

$array['content'] = array(
    1 => file_get_contents('file_b.php')
);

$array['stylesheets'] = array(
    1 => 'admin'
);
```

**file_b.php**

```
<div class="something">
    <?php
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            echo 'This is a ' . $value . '\n';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

This code will make the `$array['content'][1]` have the value `<div class="something"> <?phpforeach($data as $key => $value) { echo 'This is a ' . $value . '\n'; } ?> </div>` instead of the actual HTML

Comment: Don't rly understand your problem. If you wanna get all code from a file -> do something else with ajax -> use code from the file you could just do "file_get_contents(..) -> ajax call -> eval()". But maybe I dont understand your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use output buffering for the include.

```
ob_start();
include(file);
$content = ob_get_clean();
$array['content'] = array(
    1 => $content
);
```

Comment: Perfect! This actually solved it.. wonderful.. Should probably read more about that ob stuff. Seems it can do a lot of powerful stuff.. Thanks a lot!